# how to return inverse relation in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

this is my **Category** model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            required: true
        },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true
    });

    Category.associate = function(models) {
        models.Category.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user' });
    };

    return Category;
}
```

and this is my **User** model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            required: true
        },
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true
    });

    return User;
}
```

this works perfectly fine if I want to show a **category** and his **user**

```
Category.findAll(include: [{ all: true }])
```

considering that a **User** belongs to many **Category** how can I display a **User** with all the **Category**?
I don't have a pivot table because the **Category** table has a **userId** column.

Comment: Where is userId column in the category table?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth sequelize automagically creates it . no need to define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what all you need :

```
// The expected inverse relation
User.hasMany(Category, {
    foreignKey: "userId"
})

// Fetching users with linked categories.
const users = await User.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Category
        }
    ]
})
```

All these code are available In [Sequelize-sscce](https://github.com/ratulSharker/sequelize-sscce/tree/stackoverflow-answer%231). Sources are avaiable [here](https://github.com/ratulSharker/sequelize-sscce/blob/stackoverflow-answer%231/src/sscce.js).

Comment: this works thanks! I just changed it to foreignKey: "userId" I was getting an error with your suggestion. can you update the answer so I can accepted? thanks!